# Will Disabled and invisible Gameobject take up performance?

Tags: unity-game-engine

If I placed a gameobject with complicated model and texture and disable its mesh renderer, will it still consume CPU and GPU resources? Will it only consume memory?

Comment: Perhaps you could try experimenting by generating a large number of objects, hiding them, and checking the Unity Profiler?

Answer (score 2):

If they have any Rigidbodies, Colliders, etc on them, they will consume a considerable amount of CPU. If you have disabled MeshRenderer and there are no more rednerers on the gameobject, than there will be 0 consumption of GPU. It will consume memory, inevitably.

Now since the object is active and working on the scene, even if it doesnt have any components and is essentially just an empty gameobject, it still will waste some CPU, but that amount will be negligable. For example if the gameobject has a tag, or a layer or if you have any Finds by name, in those cases it will consume some CPU.

The best way is to deactivate the GameObject and than re-Activate it when you need it SetActive(false/true);