# Will Disabled GameObjects take up performance in Unity?

Tags: unity-game-engine

Hi I wanted to know if I have a GameObject in Unity, but have no components attached to it except for the `Transform` and it will be `SetActive(false)`. Does this take up performance. I know that this question have been already asked over here :

[Will Disabled and invisible Gameobject take up performance?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46573126/will-disabled-and-invisible-gameobject-take-up-performance)

But I am still confused with the answer and its is 3 years old and all of the answers I researched are kinda old, so I do not know if `enabling` and `disabling` objects will still take up performance as it might be updated, I don't know. I need this info cause I am making a Procedural Generation in Unity.

Thanks :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as the GameObjects present in the scene are concerned, they will take up a bit of CPU and Memory because though inactive, they are still present in the scene, and you can still access them in the scene.
But this is negligible in most cases. Because all the components on the gameObject itself will be Inactive (Transform, Renderers, Scripts).

However, When you have scripts attached to the GameObjects, if they are Rendering something, etc, Keeping them Inactive will save your CPU and GPU when it comes to those components, because there is no computing kicking in until the GameObject is actually active in the scene.
But having inactive GameObjects in the scene in general is not an issue at all. It takes up negligible performance and memory in an average use case.